# Make from 2 columns 1

Tags: r

This should be fairly simple, not sure why I can't find the answer.

I have a dataset with 15 variables (columns) from a csv. 2 variables are called `Cancer` and `copyofCancer`, indicating whether or not someone has cancer. Those 2 columns should become 1 new column where column `copyofCancer` is appended to `Cancer`.

When combining the 2 columns into 1 new column, I should have the new column added in the complete dataset of 15 variables. I found solutions where I had a dataframe with only 3 variables (`Cancer`, `copyofCancer`, `Cancercombined`) but could not find a way to have this added to my complete dataset of 15 variables. My dataset is called `risk`

For example

```
Cancer:  yes no yes no
copyofCancer: no no yes no
```

becomes column:

```
Cancercombined: yes no yes no no no yes no
```

Comment: Not clear regarding the input format and expected output. Do you have a (named) vector? A `data.frame`? Perhaps you are after `cbind()`? Or `c()`? PS. Not my downvote.

Comment: @Kirsten Welcome to SO! Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Following the guidelines will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I think you need `c(t(data))` or `unlist(data)`  It

Comment: @akrun Thanks for the answers. In c(t(data) or unlist(data) how do I refer to the columns that need to be merged. And I need to create a new column. So c(t(risk)  -> risk dataset has columns Cancer and Copyofcancer

Comment: It is a vector.  So, you can just wrap `data.frame(newcol = unlist(data))`

Comment: You can combine the two columns by doing  `c(risk$Cancer, risk$copyofCancer)` but you cannot add it to your dataframe since now the length is doubled.

Comment: @RonakShah Oh thanks for your clear answer. Now I understand the problem, I was earlier indeed able combine the 2 columns with c but not add it to the dataset.

Comment: @RonakShah will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the two columns by using `c` or `append` i.e

```
c(risk$Cancer, risk$copyofCancer)
```

Or

```
append(risk$Cancer, risk$copyofCancer)
```

However, since this is combination of two columns length of it has been doubled so you cannot add it to the dataframe.